# Announcing a winner code

Tags: python-3.x

I was wondering if anyone could help me with this. This is a simple rugby winner
announcer. The code seems to run fine sometimes and not other times.

```
team1 = input ("Team 1: ")
score1 = input("Score: ")
team2 = input("Team 2: ")
score2 = input("Score: ")

if score1 >= score2:
  print (team1 + " beat " + team2 + " " + score1 + "-" + score2)
else:
  print(team2 + " beat " + team1 + " " + score2 + "-" + score1)
```

This is the example that is working:

```
Team 1: england
Score: 35
Team 2: fiji
Score: 11
england beat fiji 35-11
```

However, when i enter this it doesn't work:

```
Team 1: Wales
Score: 54
Team 2: Urguary
Score: 9
Urguary beat Wales 9-54
```

Can anyone see what is wrong? any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison is not working the way you expect because it is comparing strings, not numbers. Strings are compared lexicographically, so `9` is higher than `54` in the same way that `Z` comes after `AA` in alphabetical order.

To make your code work, convert the scores you get from the user to integers with `int`:

```
team1 = input ("Team 1: ")
score1 = int(input("Score: "))
team2 = input("Team 2: ")
score2 = int(input("Score: "))
```

Comment: Beat me by 7 seconds.

Comment: Thankyou. Worked Great

Answer (score 0):

```
team1 = input ("Team 1: ")
score1 = input("Score: ")
team2 = input("Team 2: ")
score2 = input("Score: ")

if int(score1) >= int(score2):
  print (team1 + " beat " + team2 + " " + score1 + "-" + score2)
else:
  print(team2 + " beat " + team1 + " " + score2 + "-" + score1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll advise
To compare the value, use integers or float when entering value or make it integer or float before comparison.

Either do immediately

> `score1 = int(input("Score: ")`

Or immediately after

> `score1 = input("Score: ")`
>   `score1 = int(score1)`

Or just as comparing

> `if int(score1) >= int(score2):`